# Creating a backwards git branch

Tags: git

I have the following branch:

```
c1--c2--c3--c4--c5--c6
```

I want to create a new branch which is the "reverse" of it. Like this:

```
c6'--c5'--c4'--c3'--c2'--c1'
```

**Why do I need this?**

I inherited a small project that had no history (it was not under revision control). I wanted to create a history for it. I did this by **removing** feature after feature after feaure. After each step I created a commit. In other words, I went backwards in time. Because it was easier.

Now I need to "reverse" the history.

Comment: I see where you're coming from and appreciate the effort this requires, but do you really need to make your life so complicated? Why not just have all this code committed with a message "Initial import". (I'm not saying what I'm suggesting is correct, but, in reality, a lot of times in such cases the effort outweighs the benefits. Consider this before taking the time to actually implement it. Perhaps in your case it does, but bare in mind that a lot of times it's a waste of time). My five cents. :)

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach:

1. Create a temporary branch and make your un-changes on it, committing each time.
2. Revert each commit on the temporary branch.
3. Create a new branch from the simplest state of the temporary branch.
4. Cherry-pick each revert commit from the temporary branch onto the final branch in the correct order.